# Multiple parameters with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an URL like this one :
http://localhost:5000/search?numAbonne=048350526&numDossier=CRMSF012345665

This is my router:

```
const Routes = ({ isSearchPageEnabled }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path={searchSFOUrl} render={(props) => { debugger; return <Redirect to={"TEST"} />}} />
    <Route path="/TEST" component={TestComponent} />
    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
  </Switch>
);

export const searchSFOUrl = `/search?numAbonne=:numAbonne&numDossier=:numDossier`;
```

But the code doesn't go through the first route. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you appending params with `?&` instead of using `path="/search/:numAbonne/:numDossier"` like this? Is there a reason?

Comment: so, does your route goes to PagenotFound component or somewhere else ?

Comment: @Avanthika that's the url users use to acces my application

Comment: It doesn't matter I have the devtools open my code should stop at debugger

Answer (score 0):

So What I did was basically create the parameters again from the URL with **[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)**:

#### Router

```
<Route
  path="/search"
  render={({ location }) => Redirection(location)}
/>
```

#### RedirectionComponent

```
export const Redirection = (location) => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const subscriberNumber = urlParams.get(subscriberSFOParameter);
  ...
};
```